Why can't I access my backend file that is used for routing(app.php)?
I am making a chat application using PHP on backend and React.js on frontend. However, I am encountering a problem with fetch API.
My fetch that calls an endpoint
    fetch('http://localhost/registration-processing',{
                    method:'POST',
                    headers:{
                        'Content-Type':'application/json'
                    },
                    body:JSON.stringify({
                        firstName:firstName,
                        lastName:lastName,
                        username:username,
                        email:email,
                        password:password
                    })
                })
                .then((response)=>{
                    if(response.ok){ 
                        return response.json();
                    }
                })
                .then((data)=>{
                    console.log('Response:'+data);
                })
                .catch((err)=>{
                    console.error('Error is this:'+err);
                })

I didn't explicitly write the port in 'localhost' since Apache runs on port 80.Fetch worked absolutely fine before installing React, where I used plain JS.
I tried with using mode:'no-cors' in fetch, and I get successful response(.then is executed, not catch) but result is Response:undefined,even after I tried with echo json_encode(object) to return value , because I think that app.php is unreachable, which is made for handling all routes and fetch requests.
I tried with configuring .htaccess like this, but no results
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /back-end/app.php [QSA,L]

This is my project structure:
├── back-end/
│   ├── app.php
│   └── .htaccess
├── front-end/
│   ├── react-environment(where fetch is)

So, just to explain further. Before, I used plain JS for fetch requests to backend, precisely app.php, and it worked fine. But now, since I set up my react using create-react-app and when I run command 'npm start', it starts react app on localhost:3000, but backend(app.php) can't be reached from react. I tried experimenting with CORS, but no changes whatsoever.

Tip: { foo: foo, bar: bar } equals to { foo, bar }

Good to know, thanks :)

Note that fetch is located in the frontend project and executed on client-side (browsers). Therefore, localhost resolves to the user's computer, not your server.
You can simply replace localhost with your deployed server IP/domain.

About replacing localhost with server IP, should I replace it only in my fetch request, or should it be configured somewhere else aswell?
